# How can we directly display/download attached document on Media path

Tags: 8, media, files

I am trying to directly display/download the attached file when the Media link is reached. Main reason behind this is to avoid providing file path directly.

For example: if a user is visiting [www.dummy.com/media/redcar_brochure/](http://www.dummy.com/media/redcar_brochure/) then they should be able to view the [www.dummy.com/sites/default/files/2021-10/redcar_brochure.pdf](http://www.dummy.com/sites/default/files/2021-10/redcar_brochure.pdf) file directly in the attached media page. This will avoid clicking the file link again after going into the media page.

I tried changing the display setting for the document under media display but that is not having a way to directly view/download the file.

Is there any other way we can achieve this, spent some time with media_alias_display https://www.drupal.org/project/media_alias_display module but no luck.

Comment: Try https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity_download

Comment: @Hudri Gave it a quick try, fits the purpose +1 for the answer, will play around to see if there is anything that needs to be addressed